# Black screen with Delphi XE8 Firemonkey + Android 4.4

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

Anybody got any idea why nu applications compiled on Delphi XE8 don't work on Android 4.4? Only black screen appears. It says it should be compatible with older Android versions.

Comment: The version of Android OS is not the only important thing but also the hardware of your mobile device. So I suggest you check again the compatibility page and your mobile hardware specifications. Also it would not hurt if you provide us with that information.

Comment: Specifically the type of processor.

Comment: It doesn't work on Xperia Z (android 4.4 kitkat), but for example applications from Delphi XE6 are working fine.

Comment: Please update your question to include this extremely critical information.

Comment: If the same app compiled under XE6 works and not under XE8 then you need to open a bugreport on Embarcadero's support website. Did you try the [syscheck](http://www.fmxexpress.com/tag/syscheck/) tool to verify your HW is supported?

Comment: Doesn't work on Xperia Z1, Nexus 5, Nexus 7, Xperia Z3 Compact, Samsung Galaxy S4 and S5... not tested on anything else, sorry... I'm not mobile store :)

Answer (score 4):

Please try to create the new empty mobile project in XE8, copy the *.dpr *.pas and *.fmx files into the project folder and add them to the project in the IDE (remember about extra graphics, sound etc - check the deploy option for them). I had similar issue and the new project with completely unchanged source files worked well. Tested with Experia Z1 Compact, Android 4.4 and 5.