# Firemonkey app freezes when it's compiled with Delphi XE8

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7, delphi-xe8

I'm developing a "small" application which creates alarms/reminders using the TNotificationCenter.
The app shows the current time on the main screen, two buttons and a label.
One button is to add new alarms, the other button is for settings.
Outside of the "viewable screen" there are two rectangles containing the components for purpose according adding alarms and the menue.
Both rectangles use a floatanimationn to be shown and hide.
When I compile the app with Delphi XE7 the application works fine on different mobiles (Galaxy S2 Android 4.2, Galaxy S3 Android 4.3, Galaxy S3 Android 4.4).
When I compile the app with Delphi XE8 the application starts fine. I also can press the menue button to show the menue. But when I press one of the menue buttons (show alarms, set sound file, quit application) it freezes.

Especially for this app it would be great if I could use Delphi XE8, because with it I can use a certain sound for the notification (TNotification.SoundName), a feature which has been introduced with XE8.

I have read a similiar problem here:
[Black screen with Delphi XE8 Firemonkey + Android 4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31490610/black-screen-with-delphi-xe8-firemonkey-android-4-4)
I followed that instructions, but it didn't help for me. I checked this way, because sometimes the app also started and just showed a black screen. But most of the time it freezes when I press one of the menue items.

You can download the project here:
http://mschlereth.de/stuff/dl/QuickAlarm.zip

---

#### Solved

I have built the application from scratch under XE8 and now it works.
Of course, I copied and pasted most of the code, but the interface is built from scratch.
That's a bit frustrating, because it probably means that I would have to do this will all of my applications if I would like to use XE8 as the preferred IDE. :-(

Comment: On android 5.0.2. i get exception on startup. Stack trace (last calls)

Fmx.Types.FindStyleResource('detailstoolbutton',true)
Fmx.Controls.TStyledControl.GetStyleObject(0xaed37800,true)
Fmx.Controls.TStyledControl.GetStyleObject(0xaed37800)
Fmx.Controls.TStyledControl.ApplyStyleLookup(0xaed37800)
Fmx.Controls.TStyledControl.SetStyleLookup(0xaed37800,'detailstoolbutton')
Fmx.Presentation.Style.TStyledPresentation.PMSetStyleLookup(0xaed37800,@0xaf3fb3d4: {MsgID = 1040, Value = 'detailstoolbutton'})

p.s. your app looks nice!

Comment: I was able to run your app after erasing "StyleBk_Win"

Comment: XingFu, it is better to put your resolution into an answer. Later when the system allows, you can accept your own answer.